# arraylist in java, getting all the data print out

Tags: java, arraylist

I am learning Java right now and I am trying to use `ArrayList` in my project, but it doesn't work. Help please...

```
public class TestCalculator {
    public static void main(String[]args){

        ArrayList<BMICalculator> bmilist = new ArrayList<>();
        //ArrayList<Double> bmilist = new ArrayList<Double>();
        do {
            double lengte = getLength("Geef de lengte in Meters:");
            double gewicht = getGewicht("Geef het gewicht in Kg:");
            BMICalculator bmi = new BMICalculator(lengte, gewicht);
            bmi.setBmi(bmi.calculateBMI());
            bmilist.add(bmi);

            for(double i = 0;i < bmilist.size(); i++){
                //System.out.println(i);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "List:" + i);

            }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Bmi: " + String.format("%s", bmi.toString()));

        } while(getUserAnswer() == 'J');

    }

    public static double getLength(String message){
        String lengte = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message);
        return  Double.parseDouble(lengte);
    }

    public static double getGewicht(String message){
        String gewicht = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message);
        return  Double.parseDouble(gewicht);
    }


    public static char getUserAnswer(){
        String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Wil je opnieuw: j/n?");
        return Character.toUpperCase(answer.charAt(0));

    }
}
```

I cant get anything print out of that list. Every time someone calculates his BMI, it should put them in an `Arraylist` and when they click "continue", no... then it should return all the BMI's they calculated.

Comment: Have you tried `bmilist.get(i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<BMICalculator> bmilist = new ArrayList<>();
        do {
            double lengte = getLength("Geef de lengte in Meters:");
            double gewicht = getGewicht("Geef het gewicht in Kg:");
            BMICalculator bmi = new BMICalculator(lengte, gewicht);
            bmi.setBmi(bmi.calculateBMI());
            bmilist.add(bmi);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("%s", bmi.toString()));
        } while(getUserAnswer() == 'J');

        System.out.println("Lengte    Gewicht   BMI");
        for(int i = 0;i < bmilist.size(); i++)
        {            System.out.printf("%-10s%-10s%s\n",bmilist.get(i).getLengte(),bmilist.get(i).getGewicht(),String.format("%.2f", bmilist.get(i).getBmi()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You misused a loop with a list structure

```
for (int i = 0; i < bmilist.size(); i++) {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "List:" + bmilist.get(i).getBmi());
}
```

Comment: I tried that, it works but it doesnt show all the data in once in a "list". I have to click "ok" to keep seeing the next BMI in the list.

Comment: Please show in what format You want to see all the list elements

Comment: I would like to see like this: for examble, if I calculate 3 times a BMI, and the user says no to continue, I would like to get this format: lengte:1.69   gewicht:69   BMI:24,02

Comment: Define  method
@Override
    public String toString () {
        return "length:" + length + "gewicht:" + gewicht + "bmi =" + bmi;
    }
 in class BMICalculator

Comment: And then call that line
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "List:" + bmilist);
 without a loop.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get this format: length:1.69 gewicht:80kg and BMI:24,25... I want to get the values under the names...1.69 should be under length en so on... I tried to use \t but it doesnt work...

Comment: I am not supposed to use the  Tostring method... I think I am supposed to get the data like in colums length and the all the lenghts that the user tried under column length, and so on...

Comment: `length   gewicht    bmi
1.67         65          23.4`

Comment: `@Override public String toString () { return String.format("length%-10sgewicht%-10sbmi%n%-17.1f%-15.2f%.2f","","",length, gewicht,bmi);}` I think this method call will do

Comment: Thanks man, How come when I print it(system.out.println or JOptionPane...) I always get those [ ] too? How can I remove them....[length:         gewicht:         bmi:
1,7              80,00          28,01]

Comment: Thr problem I am having now with your code is that, everytime I calculate BMI, and after 3 times for example, when I print it out, it keeps repeating length, gewicht and BMI... its supposed to appear only one time and the three calculations just beneath them... Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: I think I understood what you want
            bmi.setBmi(bmi.calculateBMI());
            bmilist.add(bmi);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(String.format("length%-10sgewicht%-10sbmi%n", "", ""));
            for (int i = 0; i < bmilist.size(); i++) {
                BMICalculator bmiCalc = bmilist.get(i);
                sb.append(String.format("  %-19.1f%-17.2f%.2f%n", bmiCalc.lengte, bmiCalc.gewicht, bmiCalc.bmi));
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "" + sb.toString());
        } while (getUserAnswer() == 'J');

Answer (score 0):

Try the **for** loop with int variable

```
    do {
            double lengte = getLength("Geef de lengte in Meters:");
            double gewicht = getGewicht("Geef het gewicht in Kg:");
            BMICalculator bmi = new BMICalculator(lengte, gewicht);
            bmi.setBmi(bmi.calculateBMI());
            bmilist.add(bmi);
            // int variable instead of double inside for loop
            for(int i = 0;i < bmilist.size(); i++){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "List:" + bmilist.get(i));
    
            }
    
   }while(getUserAnswer() == 'J');
```